# Applying Transform to a Huge Model

Tags: shaders

So I have a character I'm making, and I ran into a slight issue with applying transform. I heard a cube is about 2 meters, I didn't really realize this was an issue until I tried putting hair on my character haha. So, I scaled her down to less than the size of a cube, and I ran into an issue with my shader of my characters eyes. Basically, it's designed so the front of the cornea is transparent so you can see the iris through it, but as soon as I applied the scale everything went wrong haha. So, is there a way I can scale the eye down and then apply the scale without it messing with the shader? I have a gradient for transparency, and after I applied the scale, even if I dropped the gradient down to nearly nothing the eyes were translucent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear from your post exactly how things "went wrong", so I can't be sure what you need. Also, I'm not an expert on shaders, though my instincts tell me that the key to this likely lies in investigating the node setup itself to see how the position and scale of the shader is controlled. It may be a simple as changing the values in a texture coordinate node to be consistent with the new scale, but I don't know. Just something to consider.

Comment: Well, I said at the end, the corneas become completely translucent. I'm sure the issue has to do with the scale of the shader, but I don't know how to fix it.